# How to prevent Volley Library from showing the link in Log after completing the request?

Tags: android, android-volley

After completing the request using volley the link is being displayed in logcat under android monitor.I need to prevent this so is there any way to do it??

```
 D/Volley: [1] Request.finish: 5801 ms: [ ] https://www.website.com/load_feeds/public?uid=xyz
```

Answer (score 2):

Set this, probably in your `Application` class:

```
VolleyLog.DEBUG = false;
```

Be aware, it seems this flag disables only `Verbose` logs and Volley still logs `Error` messages.

Comment: Where exactly should i put this?

Comment: You have to set this only one time. Set this before initiating any Volley requests. Possibly in your `Application` class or in your Volley singleton class.